# Can't put Turkish characters in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, character-encoding

When I echo some Turkish characters like:

```
echo "ÇŞİĞÖÜ, çşıüğö";
```

There is no problem:
http://i.hizliresim.com/kj9kov.png
But when I encode this string in a JSON array, and put the encoded string in mysql db, it shows like:
{"otherComments":"u00c7u015eu0130u011eu00d6u00dc, u00e7u015fu0131u00fcu011fu00f6"}

and when I do not encode it in a JSON array, it just shows "?" instead of Turkish characters.
I already have this code in my php file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');
```

I have no idea what else to do.

This is the code in my dbconnect file:

```
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->con);
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->con);
    mysql_query("SET COLLATION_COLLECTION='utf8_turkish_ci'", $this->con);
    mysql_select_db("mehmeta3_team6", $this->con);
```

The settings for the selected schema:
http://i.hizliresim.com/gkrAZN.png

The settings for the table and the column:
http://i.hizliresim.com/YvQlrE.png

Comment: Check that you have set UTF-8 as the db: connection/db name/table/column charset.

Comment: check the database whether the datas are stored in turkis or ?? .. it it is ??  then add N before the values in insert Query...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/1935077

Comment: Jiml, I updated my question. I already have done all you said.

Comment: I made a mistake in this line mysql_query("SET COLLATION_COLLECTION='utf8_turkish_ci'", $this->con);
 it should be connection, not collection :)

Comment: How did you create the JSON?  It should have only utf8 characters, not "uxxxx" encodings.  `$json = json_encode($string);` is all it takes in PHP.  All accented Turkish letters are 2 bytes in utf8: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#turkish .

Answer (score 2):

```
its not the db side problem
```

when you convert it to json format echo that string
you will see it converts it to some different format may be to ascii values of those special characters. even if you decode that result it will produce a different result not the strin you encode.
i think try to insert in the database without encodin i mean simple string like ÇŞİĞÖÜ
may be that can work

Comment: Tried, made it worse :)